# Laravel Projects are lost in VirtualBox?

Tags: laravel, virtualbox

I'm using homestead and vagrant in my windows OS.

After restarting computer, all laravel projects are lost in vagrant ?

How did this happen ? And How can I reinstall them all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type this;

```
vagrant reload
```